# jQuery check/uncheck problems

Tags: asp.net, jquery, radio-button

I'm using a gridview that has a radio button in one of the columns. It's used as a true/false flag. Anyways, because of the nature of my project, I require javascript to uncheck any radio buttons when I check another one. This works fine, except that my gridview is wrapped in an update panel. I am taking care of reintializing the jQuery on autopost back, but what's happening is upon post back, removing my checked radio button and not putting it back. If I don't use the jQuery it works fine(but then I don't get the button exclusitivity), so I think its my code. Here's the code I have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        $("input").click(function () {
            $("input").removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).attr('checked','checked');
        });
    }
    $("input").click(function () {
        $("input").removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).attr(':checked');
    });

});
```

Is there a better way to write this code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing some of my t-sql code and not having to use jquery at all.

Answer (score 0):

couple of things:

```
$(this).attr(':checked'); //this doesnt look right.. what are you trying to do here?

$('input') // this will target all input fields on the page, all radio buttons, textboxes etc. i don't think u want that. try giving the radio's IDs and use the ID selector to select them in jQuery
```

Comment: on radio button click I'm trying to uncheck all radio buttons and then check just the one that I clicked on. It should have looked like the previous line of code, didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you set the name (not the ID) of the radio buttons to be the same, HTML will automatically make the selection exclusive for you without any jQuery needed. That's how a radio box differs from a checkbox. I'd look into that first as you shouldn't need a bunch of JS to do what HTML does built in if you set it up right.

Comment: I can't do it that way because i'm using the gridview, it has an edit template and its regular template. Only javascript can successfully remove the other radios checked status in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code like this:

`if( $('input.any-radio').length ){
$('input.any-radio').change(function(){ $('input.any-radio').removeAttr('checked'); $(this).attr('checked', 'checked'); });}`

and it works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try it

For Radio Button

```
function toggleCheckRadioButton(sender) {
    var res;
    if ($(sender).attr('previousValue') == 'true') {
        $(sender).attr('checked', false)
        res = false;
    } 
    else {
        $(sender).attr('checked', true);
        res = true;
    }

    $('form input[type="radio"][name$="' + $(sender).attr('name') + '"]').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('previousValue', false);        
    });

    $(sender).attr('previousValue', res);    
}
```

For Radio List

```
function initToggleCheckRadioList(sender) {
    $(sender).find('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () { toggleCheckRadioButton(this); });
    });
}
```